# How to use parentheses in select formula field

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb, formula, parentheses

> actual table and select is too long so i will use simple example for my question

i have a table (**tbl_price**) with 2 column (**price1**,**price2**)
when select fields with simple select like this

```
 SELECT price1-price2 from tbl_price
```

i have no problem until
use parentheses in select, no record will return:

```
 SELECT (price1-price2) from tbl_price
```

actualy i want to select like this :

```
 SELECT (price1-price2)/price2*100 from tbl_price
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: That example is fine. I suspect you have a syntax mistake in the actual query you run (not in the simplified example above), but you aren't checking for errors. So "no record will return" really means the query can't be parsed successfully. Solution: **check for errors** every time you prepare or execute a query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to process the result in PHP?

Try it like this:

in MySql:

```
SELECT ((price1-price2)/price2*100) AS result FROM tbl_price
```

in PHP:

```
echo($row['result']);
```

Comment: i checked and result is empty . no error occurred ( my local db is Mariadb)

Comment: i found that if use + (price1+price2) it will work but use -  (price1-price2) will return no records. why?

Comment: it's ok on mariadb and empty  in mysql :(

Answer (score 0):

I found problem ! 
my fields were unsigned int.so result will be unsigned and no records will return .but if i change columns to signed . results will be ok